# C# Process CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, file, csv

I have the following CSV file with this header:

`AccountOwnerEmail  PartnerName EnrollmentID Customer LicensingProgram Country Culture Issue`

with lines like this:

`v-dakash@catalysis.com,"HEY"? Tester, 12345789,"Catalysis", LLC., Enterprise 6 TEST, etc,etc ,etc`

I have a method to separate the lines into the corresponding columns:

```
var columns = columnsRegex.Matches(line)
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(m=> m.Value.Trim('\"', '\'', ' ', '\t'))
                          .ToList();
```

Here's the definition for `columnsRegex`:

```
private static Regex columnsRegex = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^,;]+");
```

My problem here is that for example the `PartnerName` content is being separated into 3 columns like `""` `"Hey"` and `"?Tester"`

I know that the CSV escapes the double quotes with another double quotes. And I have already checked another posts similar to this that recomends to add the reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` but that is not working for me. Its there any other approach to take to correctly process the CSV content?

Comment: There are multiple CSV parsers for .NET out there (see [a NuGet Search](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv)).

Comment: This is NOT a CSV. To parse it with a regex is right, field name is `^\w+:` and everything else `.*` is its value. Ignore the header (if records are somehow separated, from example by a full blank line, otherwise just use it to count the number of fields in each record `header.Split(' ').Length`). Alternatively a simple `line.IndexOf(":")` might also work pretty well in this case...

Comment: "with lines like this" That isn't CSV

Comment: @Richard If it was an actual CSV file then yes... This is essentially a text file.

Comment: Can you share more lines of the file?

Comment: Since you know the header text it should be easy to strip them out of each line,  As mentioned, that is not a CSV

Comment: CSV = comma separated values, space can not be a separator

Comment: Is that what a typical value of `line` looks like?  If not, that's what we need to see.

Comment: They are separeted with commas I put it that way to better to better match each column with the content

Comment: I have editted the text to show the real CSV line.

Comment: @Ian yes, each value of line looks like the one I just editted, I cannot use any library due to compliance

Comment: @pedrodotnet due to compliance, you will have poorly alternative to a library. A new wheel without any test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) for it. It's a very nice library to parse CSV documents. Use nuget package:

```
Install-Package CsvHelper
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyCsvRecord>();
```

Where `MyCsvRecord` is your CSV row e.g.:

```
public class MyCsvRecord
{
    public string AccountOwnerEmail { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: My problem with this is that is returnin `illegal character in path` error because of the double quotes. And I cannot delete them, I need to show the exact content of the file

Comment: @pedrodotnet can you open your document in Excel? I feel like your "CSV" document is not well formatted.

Comment: Yes, It's an Excel file, I upload the excel to my solution to process it.

Comment: I cannot create the class`MyCsvRecord` because not all the excels contains the same columns

Comment: @pedrodotnet You can create a class that has all the nullable fields or you can use `dynamic` approach instead. See the documentation.

Comment: I used CSVHelper and is really nice. i solved all of my problems with simple custom things. I fixed /r/n charts in a column, parsed a column to multiple columns, etc. @pedrodotnet go to this way, will be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Added another parser method, fixed line and test parsing output.

I would say, that your regular expression pattern is wrong. It does not allow to use (doubled) `"` character in `"` prefixed values. The same problem is for `'`

```
internal static class Program
{
  private const string wrongLine = "v-dakash@catalysis.com,\"HEY\"? Tester, 12345789,\"Catalysis\", LLC., Enterprise 6 TEST, etc,etc ,etc";
  private const string fixedLine = "v-dakash@catalysis.com,\"\"\"HEY\"\"? Tester\", 12345789,\"Catalysis\", LLC., Enterprise 6 TEST, etc,etc ,etc";

  private static readonly Regex wrongPattern = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^,;]+");
  private static readonly Regex fixedPattern = new Regex("((?:\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\")|(?:'((?:[^']|'')*)')|([^,;]*))(?:[,;]|$)");

  private static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("***  Wrong line: ***");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Parse(wrongLine);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("***  Fixed line: ***");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Parse(fixedLine);
  }

  private static void Parse(string line)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("--- [Original Regex] ---");

    var matches = wrongPattern.Matches(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("'" + matches[i].Value + "'");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("--- [Fixed Regex] ---");
    Console.WriteLine();

    matches = fixedPattern.Matches(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("'" + GetValue(matches[i]) + "'");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("--- [Correct(?) parser] ---");
    Console.WriteLine();

    var position = 0;
    while (position < line.Length)
    {
      var value = GetValue(line, ref position);
      Console.WriteLine("'" + value + "'");
    }
  }

  private static string GetValue(Match match)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[2].Value))
    {
      return (match.Groups[2].Value.Replace("\"\"", "\""));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[3].Value))
    {
      return (match.Groups[3].Value.Replace("''", "'"));
    }

    return (match.Groups[4].Value.Replace("''", "'"));
  }

  private static string GetValue(string line, ref int position)
  {
    string value;
    char? prefix;
    string endWith;
    switch (line[position])
    {
    case '\'':
    case '\"':
      prefix = line[position];
      endWith = prefix + ",";
      position++;
      break;

    default:
      prefix = null;
      endWith = ",";
      break;
    }

    var endPosition = line.IndexOf(endWith, position);
    if (endPosition < 0 && prefix.HasValue)
    {
      if (line[line.Length - 1] == prefix.Value)
      {
        value = line.Substring(position, line.Length - 1 - position);
        position = line.Length;
        return Fixprefix(value, prefix.Value.ToString());
      }

      position--;
      endPosition = line.IndexOf(',', position);
    }

    if (endPosition < 0)
    {
      value = line.Substring(position);
      position = line.Length;
      return value;
    }

    if (prefix.HasValue)
    {
      value = line.Substring(position, endPosition - position);
      position = endPosition + endWith.Length;
      return Fixprefix(value, prefix.Value.ToString());
    }

    value = line.Substring(position, endPosition - position);
    position = endPosition + endWith.Length;
    return value;
  }

  private static string Fixprefix(string value, string prefix) => value.Replace(prefix + prefix, prefix);
}
```

The 'fixed `Regex` pattern' still has a bug, but I leave it at current state...

*(Figure your self how to fix this parsing.)*

[Parser test](https://regex101.com/r/r8XhhH/2)

Output window:

```
***  Wrong line: ***

--- [Original Regex] ---
'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'"HEY"'
'? Tester'
' 12345789'
'"Catalysis"'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'

--- [Fixed Regex] ---

'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'"HEY"? Tester'
' 12345789'
'Catalysis'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'
''

--- [Correct(?) parser] ---

'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'HEY"? Tester, 12345789,"Catalysis'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'


***  Fixed line: ***

--- [Original Regex] ---
'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'""'
'"HEY"'
'"? Tester"'
' 12345789'
'"Catalysis"'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'

--- [Fixed Regex] ---

'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'"HEY"? Tester'
' 12345789'
'Catalysis'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'
''

--- [Correct(?) parser] ---

'v-dakash@catalysis.com'
'"HEY"? Tester'
' 12345789'
'Catalysis'
' LLC.'
' Enterprise 6 TEST'
' etc'
'etc '
'etc'
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the Regex, the problem is that the csv adds double quotes to escape the double quotes so the c# is reading like `"""HEY""?TEST"`

Comment: @pedrodotnet: The real problem (one of) is the Regex. It does not allow `"` character in `"` prefixed item value *(e.g. `"the value is ""a"""` will not be parsed correctly)*. Even in my example there is one of two possible parse results. *(And IMHO, the incorrect one.)* But this parses the *(incorrect)* string the way, it should be parsed according to request.

Comment: The new Regex helped a little bit, now is not splitting the content in different columns but the `"Hey?Tester"` is being parsed as `"Hey\"\?Tester\"`

Comment: Even in the corrected example? What is the incorrect line?

Comment: For example this line `v-dakash@catalysis.com,"HEY"? Tester, 12345789,"Catalysis", LLC., Enterprise 6 TEST, etc,etc ,etc`   the value `"HEY"? Tester` is returned as `\"Hey\"\?Tester"`

Comment: This is highly unlikely. There is no code, that somewhere adds a `\` character. And since the value `"HEY"? Tester` is invalid, the value should be `"HEY"? Tester`. See the example *(full code in post)* what is the real value. You can not see the real value in debugger. There is prefixed value.

Comment: Heres is the output using the parsing method:

`v-dakash@catalysis.com,"""HEY""? Tester",123456789,"""Catalysis"", LLC.",Enterprise 6 TEST,United States,EN-US,Quote marks used in Partner and Customer Name`